# Как удалить файл из чужой программы на android?

Tags: java, android, sdk

Как удалить файл из чужой программы на android?

Моя программа такая `com.asd.project`

Я хочу удалить файл Fog из приложения который находится в

```
/data/data/com.frog.fog/Fog
```

Как это сделать? Уже 4 дня голову ломаю. На стеке много читал, но ничего не нашел такого чтобы было мне понятно.

```
try {
        final Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            File file=new    File(Environment.getDataDirectory()+"/data/com.frog.fog/Fog");
            file.delete();
            if (file.isFile()) Log.e("asd","ASDADDDSAADSDS");
        }
    });

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("asdasd","ERROR");
    }
```

Вопросы.

1. Я как понял, чтобы что-то сделать с другим файлом который находится по пути `/data/data/`, нужны root права?
2. Как правильно сделать, чтобы можно было изменять или удалять файлы и папки в пути `/data/data/` и тут название любого приложения...

Comment: Вообще-то ОС давать не должна вытворять такие фишки. Каждое приложение живет независимо от остальных (sandbox типа) и не должно иметь права мешать другим программам работать.

Comment: Отнють не согласен с вами. Потому что Приложение так называемое. rootExplorer позволяет с root правами удалять, переименовывать, менять вставлять и что только не делать со всей ОС.

rootExplorer это обычное apk приложение, значит люди как то же сделали это. Значит возможно

Comment: Рут на то и рут, чтобы уметь такие вещи, а обычное приложение не умеет лазать к другим в песочницы. Так что да, получай для приложения рута и лазай по файловой системе.

Comment: @Vesper, А как мне получить возможность то?. Я прописал exec(su). При запуске приложение появляется штука типо. Разрешить рут я говорю да. Но файл не удаляется. Тогда на что я дал рут то не понятно. Код рабочий. Моежте проверить сами

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто выполнить `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");` мало, права рута получит только порожденный процесс, а без командной строки он сразу завершится. Но можно заслать ему команду Linux для удаления файла, если известен точный путь до файла, [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194725/run-android-program-as-root) есть для этого заготовка кода, вместо `COMMAND` нужно написать вызов `rm -f /data/data/com.frog.fog/Fog`. Вроде вот так должно сработать:

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "/system/bin/rm", "-f", "/data/data/com.frog.fog/Fog" });
```

Здесь указан абсолютный путь, он, возможно, неверный, а для поиска верного пути нужно искать сам файл, вплоть до реального вызова `find /data -name "Fog"`.

Вообще, особо ушлые люди запускают сразу шелл, получают потоки от процесса и начинают обмениваться с ним данными как с командной строкой - найти файл, удалить файл, что-то скопировать и т.д., и парсят текстовый вывод. Для задачи "просто удалить файл" это может быть излишеством, но получить вывод процесса всегда полезно, может, там file not found, и нужно дальше отлаживать программу, без захвата вывода ты этого не поймешь.

Comment: Я умею удалять файлы через консоль. Вот так rm -r папка. но как мне прописать это в консоли? 

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su rm -r MyFolder"); так чтоли?

Comment: `su -c rm -r /path/to/myfolder` - нужен свитч -c (выполнить команду).

Comment: ЗАРАБОТАЛО!!!!! Спасибо)